# Placeholder in Select component

Tags: material-ui

I use https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/v1-beta

Can I make a placeholder in the `Select` component?

```
<Select
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  input={<Input />}
>
  <MenuItem value={''}>Any</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={'Male'}>Male</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={'Female'}>Female</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -5):

You should use FormControl and InputLabel components.

Example from the select component material page:

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Age</InputLabel>
      <Select
        value={this.state.age}
        onChange={this.handleChange('age')}
        input={<Input id="age-simple" />}
      >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

Hope it helps :)